# How to assign contact Role by code?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, role

I have to assign a *Role* for a *Customer*?

I am creating a *Customer*, after that, for creating a role,

I have already the contact in **GlobalAddressBook** , I want to add a *ROLE* for this contact, I don't wanto to create a new record in *DirPartyTable*.

I use this code:

```
DirPartyRelationship::createRecordRelations("Vendor" , CompanyInfo::find().RecId , this.findDirPartyRecid().RecId , curext());
```

I created a record on Table *DirPartyRelationship* , but on GlobalAddress form (in HomePage) I can't find the new role for my Vendor.

I sow some *classes* : DirParty , and nother, but I don't know how to use? If I have to use.

Is there a class for creating a role by code? I don't know how I to do this.

Thanks all,

Enjoy!
I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one of the possible solution.

If I already have a contact (example Vendor o Customer)
I have to take its value in field `Party` and use this value forcing in the same field in the Cust/Vend Table.

Exaple: if I have a Customer, go on `VendTable`, I take the value in `Party` field. 
When I create in `CustTable` my new Customer I force the value taken into in `VendTable`in field `CustTable.Party`.

Automatically when I create a customer create a new role, with this system associate a Role.(for my Company).

If you have more information updated my answer.
Thanks all!

References:

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/170776 ;

https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/174210?pi51736=1#responses ;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vendtable.aspx .